# How do I create a user which will login using ssh with key only authentication?

Tags: ssh, puttygen

I'm trying to setup new user which will be able to login with key only. Also, I need to change his home dir to /var/www/website.
Here are the steps I've done and result

1. created a user with `useradd mark`
2. generated a key on win machine with puttygen (ssh-2 rsa), added key passphrase, saved private key to .ppk file.
3. Copied public key into servers authorized_keys file. It is copied in one line (i found that copying in multiple lines can result with problems)

On the server, only logging with key is allowed.
The error that I get when I try to connect with new user and new key thru winscp is

```
No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
Server refused our key.
Authentication failed.
```

whoami; `root`

ls -ld /home/mark /home/mark/.ssh /home/mark/.ssh/authorized_keys;

`drwxrwxrwx 3 mark mark 4096 Nov 19 23:39 /home/mark
drwxrwxrwx 2 mark mark 4096 Nov 19 23:41 /home/mark/.ssh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mark mark  401 Nov 20 00:13 /home/mark/.ssh/authorized_keys`

full stack of log for one attempt 
`Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug1: userauth-request for user mark service ssh-connection method publickey
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 1
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug3: mm_key_allowed entering
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 21
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 22
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 21
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x7fb00ff9ebc0
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 508/508 (e=0/0)
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug1: trying public key file /home/mark/.ssh/authorized_keys
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/mark/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 508/508 (e=0/0)
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug1: trying public key file /home/mark/.ssh/authorized_keys
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/mark/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: Failed publickey for mark from 178.148.168.147 port 62172 ssh2
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x7fb00ff9ebc0 is not allowed
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 22
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-rsa
Nov 20 16:33:15 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug3: Wrote 96 bytes for a total of 1965
Nov 20 16:33:17 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: Received disconnect from IP : 13: User request
Nov 20 16:33:17 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug1: do_cleanup
Nov 20 16:33:17 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
Nov 20 16:33:17 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 80
Nov 20 16:33:17 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 81
Nov 20 16:33:17 HOSTNAME sshd[12419]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Nov 20 16:33:17 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 80
Nov 20 16:33:17 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 81
Nov 20 16:33:17 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Nov 20 16:33:17 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug1: do_cleanup
Nov 20 16:33:17 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug1: PAM: cleanup
Nov 20 16:33:17 HOSTNAME sshd[12418]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
Nov 20 16:33:22 HOSTNAME sshd[11630]: debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
Nov 20 16:33:52 HOSTNAME sshd[11630]: debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 80 bytes for a total of 7077
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 96 bytes for a total of 7173
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 4160 bytes for a total of 11333
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 4160 bytes for a total of 15493
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 4160 bytes for a total of 19653
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 8272 bytes for a total of 27925
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 4160 bytes for a total of 32085
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 48533
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 64981
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 81429
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 25892 bytes for a total of 107321
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 35040 bytes for a total of 142361
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 40880 bytes for a total of 183241
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 43800 bytes for a total of 227041
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 35316 bytes for a total of 262357
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 278805
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 295253
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 311701
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 328149
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 344597
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 361045
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 32896 bytes for a total of 393941
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 410389
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 426837
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 443285
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 459733
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 476181
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 492629
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 509077
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 525525
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 541973
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 558421
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 574869
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 591317
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 607765
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 624213
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 640661
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 657109
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 32896 bytes for a total of 690005
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 706453
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 722901
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 739349
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 755797
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 772245
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 788693
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 805141
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 821589
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 838037
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 854485
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 870933
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 887381
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 903829
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 920277
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 936725
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 953173
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 969621
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 986069
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1002517
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1018965
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1035413
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1051861
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1068309
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1084757
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1101205
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1117653
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1134101
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1150549
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1166997
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1183445
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1199893
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1216341
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1232789
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1249237
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1265685
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1282133
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1298581
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1315029
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1331477
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1347925
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1364373
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1380821
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1397269
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1413717
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1430165
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1446613
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1463061
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1479509
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1495957
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1512405
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1528853
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1545301
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1561749
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1578197
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1594645
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1611093
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1627541
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1643989
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1660437
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1676885
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1693333
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1709781
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1726229
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1742677
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1759125
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1775573
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1792021
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1808469
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1824917
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1841365
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1857813
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1874261
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1890709
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1907157
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1923605
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1940053
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1956501
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1972949
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 1989397
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2005845
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2022293
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2038741
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2055189
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2071637
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2088085
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2104533
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2120981
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2137429
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2153877
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2170325
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2186773
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2203221
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2219669
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2236117
Nov 20 16:33:53 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2252565
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2269013
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2285461
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2301909
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2318357
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2334805
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2351253
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2367701
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2384149
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2400597
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2417045
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2433493
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2449941
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2466389
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2482837
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2499285
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2515733
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2532181
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2548629
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2565077
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2581525
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2597973
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2614421
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2630869
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2647317
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2663765
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2680213
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2696661
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2713109
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2729557
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2746005
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2762453
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2778901
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2795349
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2811797
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2828245
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2844693
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2861141
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2877589
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2894037
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2910485
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2926933
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2943381
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2959829
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2976277
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 2992725
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3009173
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3025621
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3042069
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3058517
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3074965
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3091413
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3107861
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3124309
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3140757
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3157205
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3173653
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3190101
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3206549
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3222997
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3239445
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3255893
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3272341
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3288789
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3305237
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3321685
Nov 20 16:33:54 HOSTNAME sshd[12187]: debug3: Wrote 16448 bytes for a total of 3338133`

Any ideas?

Comment: did you use puttygen to convert the public key from putty format to openssh format?

Comment: @Hangin on in quiet desperation No, i used puttygen to create the key  - moved the cursor around the screen, added Key passphrase changed number of bits to 2048 and then "save private key"

Answer (score 1):

Your description seems good, but you may have pasted the key in an incorrect way (some typo or a missing character). To help you diagnose the problem, you can do the following:

Edit the config file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, set log level:

```
LogLevel DEBUG3
```

and reload ssh

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh reload
```

This increases the log level for ssh daemon so that you can find out what's going on. Look at ssh log file `/var/log/auth.log` for problems while trying to login.

Comment: i get  
`/etc/init.d/ssh: No such file or directory `
although, i have sshd in that directory

Comment: no `/var/log/auth.log` either.  I have `/var/log/audit/audit.log` where i can find some info about loging, i guess this is it?

`type=USER_ERR msg=audit(1479553728.025:100688): user pid=13360 uid=0 auid=0 ses=1469 msg='op=PAM:bad_ident acct="?" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=cable-MYIP.MYDOMAIN addr=MYIP terminal=ssh res=failed'`

Comment: @Aleks: What is your distribution? Some paths/files may be different.

Comment: CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

Answer (score 1):

Check `/var/log/secure` for `sshd` errors. There may be errors due to bad ownership and/or permissions on user's home dir, `.ssh` dir or `authorized_keys` file itself so `sshd` will ignore that file.
Also check `AuthorizedKeysFile` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`: sshd may be configured to look for `authorized_keys` file somewhere else and not in users home directory. If it is your case, then just put `authorized_keys` file on right place with right owner and permissions and try one more time.

Comment: Thanks, this is the error `Could not open authorized keys '/home/marko/.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory`
But i'm not sure why is it looking for his key there, since all other keys are in the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Maybe because he is not in the root group?
In the config, i have 
`AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys`
`# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes`
should i uncommnet last line ?

Comment: @aleks As all other keys are in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` that means all other users could login as `root`. It's very insecure but if you are comfortable with that, may be better to leave everythin as it is. And the log record `Could not open authorized keys '/home/marko/.ssh/authorized_keys...` tells that you try to login as user *marko* while you wrote you've added user `mark`. So you should check login you use to access server (it should be `mark`) and put key to `/home/mark/.ssh/authorized_keys`). And right now better not to change anything in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: mark-marko it qas just a typo here, not on server.

I've placed file `/home/mark/.ssh/authorized_keys` and pasted key in it.
Now i get different error `Could not open authorized keys '/home/mark/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied`
I've added even 777 to both .ssh folder and authorized_keys file but result stays the same - Permission denied.
Thanx for your help

Comment: I'm confused on permissions you have and errors you got. Could you share permissions, last errors from ssh and describe what you are doing when get `Permission denied error`? Next commands should help you: `whoami; ls -ld /home/mark /home/mark/.ssh /home/mark/.ssh/authorized_keys; sudo tail /var/log/secure`. And you could add this information to your main post so it will be easier to read and understand your problem.

Comment: and two more commands to check `authorized_keys` file: `wc -l /home/mark/.ssh/authorized_keys; egrep -c -w 'ssh-[rd]sa' /home/mark/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: here are the results
`1 /home/mark/.ssh/authorized_keys`
`1`

Comment: And what about `ls -ld` and `sudo tail` commands?

Comment: i've added it to main description.

Comment: Sorry, I forget that you use Centos. I've added another answer about `Selinux`. But permissions must be fixed too: sshd will not use `authorized_keys` if they and `.ssh` folders are group- and others-writable.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forget that you use `Centos` and it has `Selinux` enabled by default. So in your case you have to allow `sshd` access folders under `/var` path. Here is a [Centos forum thread](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=9122) describe how to allow `sshd` access `authorized_keys` outside `/home` folder.